# Nonsensical NullPointerException/Variable decides not to exist

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, bukkit

I've been developing a plugin for Spigot for a few days now, and have already made several StackOverflow posts about it. However, this one is the most baffling.

```
package redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.modifiers;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;
import redempt.divinity.ability.AbilityType;
import redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.ProjectileModifier;

public class NoGravity extends ProjectileModifier {
    private Vector vector;
    Location lastpos;
    @Override
    public void onUse(Player player, Entity projectile) {
        vector = player.getLocation().getDirection().normalize().clone();
        System.out.println(vector);
        lastpos = projectile.getLocation();
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "No gravity";
    }
    @Override
    public Material getRepresentation() {
        return Material.FEATHER;
    }
    @Override
    public AbilityType getType() {
        return AbilityType.PROJECTILE;
    }
    @Override
    public void onHit(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(Entity entity) {
//      if (lastpos == null || vector == null) {
//          return;
//      }
        System.out.println(vector);
        if (entity.getLocation().getBlock().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) {
            entity.setVelocity(vector);
        }
        lastpos = entity.getLocation();
    }
}
```

Now the console output:

```
[11:49:13 INFO]: null
[11:49:13 INFO]: null
[11:49:13 INFO]: null
[11:49:14 INFO]: 0.18347871628032447,-0.275177341220671,-0.9437229421556131
[11:49:14 INFO]: null
[11:49:14 INFO]: null
[11:49:14 INFO]: null
[11:49:14 INFO]: null
[11:49:14 INFO]: null
[11:49:14 INFO]: null
..And so on
```

As you can see, the variable 'vector' is a private Vector object. For some reason, though, it doesn't seem to like existing very much, and seems to only not be null on occasion. Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Comment: Well the first thing I'd do is change your logging so you can tell which line comes from which method. I would also print `this` so you can tell whether you have multiple instances involved.

Comment: Is this the actual code? The messages look like log messages, but the code has `System.out.println()` statements, not log statements. I don't know what's formatting the line to have [HH:MM:SS INFO]: on it.

Comment: Noticed you're using `clone`...did you confirm someone actually put any code in `clone`?

Comment: That's the ONLY method giving an output to console

Comment: Well, I tried without clone, but that has the same issue

Comment: The reason it has that system.out formatting is because it's Bukkit.

Comment: Well, the ```null``` output is coming from your ```onTick``` method, so somewhere a ```NoGravity``` is created and then ```onTick``` is called on it, before ```onUse```.

Comment: By the way, for the sake of code clarity, there's no need to call .equals on enums; just use ==.

Comment: I checked, and onUse() is always called before onTick()

Comment: If `onUse` was always called before `onTick`, the initially `null` instance variables in the `NoGravity` class would have non-null values, since `player.getLocation().getDirection()` and `entity.getLocation()` never return `null`, and if either arguments to `onUse` were `null` you would get a `NullPointerException`. Could we see where the `NoGravity` class is used? Also: `getDirection()` already returns a unit vector, so there's no need to normalize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there were somehow 2 instances of the exact same object, except one got its onUse() called, and the other did not. I fixed the issue now.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that people know the question has been resolved :)